# Is there such a thing as Dynamic CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is both a question and a statement.

The question is: Is there such a thing as DYNAMIC CSS?  In other words - can you do this:

```
<span class="size(24pt)">This is a test</span>
```

And have CSS recognize the 24pt as being an argument that is passed to the CSS?  The CSS would be:

```
<style>
.size { font-size: #1; }
</style>
```

Or maybe

```
<style>
.size { font-size: $1; }
</style>
```

Statement: If it can't do this - why not?  Static CSS sort of defeats the purpose of CSS.  CSS, like HTML and Javascript, should be dynamic and accept arguments.  If CSS accepted arguments then you wouldn't need to do this:

```
<style>
.size9 { font-size: 9pt; }
.size10 { font-size: 10pt; }
...and so forth
</style>
```

I continue to be amazed at the short-sightedness of those who design these things.  It's like Bill Gates saying we will never need more than 640K or Steve Jobs saying we don't need color.  The need for being able to pass arguments to CSS is essential to reducing and eliminating redundancy in CSS.

Sorry - a bit of a rant - but I have searched for a way to do Dynamic CSS for months and haven't found any way to do it.  So IS there a way to do it?

Notes: How would it be done?  Every CSS element would be considered a function.  (Which it just about is already.)  Thus all CSS elements would accept an argument list.  (ie: A { bold; } could become A{ $1; } and a class statement of class="a(bold)" would generate A{ bold; }.  This might seem dumb to some - but the real idea becomes apparent when you can make A{*} mean "A{-anything-}".  So then

```
<style>
.size { font-size: *; }
.td{ text-decorations: *; }
A{*}
</style>
```

when sent class="a(bold size(14pt) td(none))" would generate A{bold; font-size:14pt; text-decorations:none;}.

Wouldn't that be neat? :-)  Is such a thing possible in CSS?

Comment: So you are talking about Stylus, LESS, SASS....

Comment: To add to @Dayan's comment: What is wrong with: http://lesscss.org/?

Comment: HTML is not dynamic and does not accept arguments....  You know that you can generate CSS dynamically just like you can with HTML, right?  The browser doesn't know or care what happens server-side.  Plus, there are entire standards around templating CSS files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reads like the introduction to a forum thread, rather than a standalone question amenable to a single answer.

Comment: So why do they call it Dynamic HTML (DHTML)? To: Puelo & Dayan - I'm checking out SASS.

Comment: FWIW, the answer to the simple question of "does CSS allow this?" is no, current CSS doesn't  have any parameter expansion of this sort (which isn't really "dynamic", just code reuse). To fill this need, pre-processor languages have been written (SASS/SCSS, Less, Stylus, etc) which generate CSS from more complex templates.

Comment: @MarkManning DHTML is a slightly old-fashioned term for manipulating the HTML on the browser using JS. You can manipulate CSS in the same way if you want to, but what your describing here isn't really "dynamic" in that sense.

Comment: To IMSoP:  I think SCSS is what I am looking for.  I'm still reading up on it but I think I'm going to mark the person who first suggested it as the answer. I'm also thinking maybe a PHP script would be a better way to handle this since there isn't anything like what I described.  SCSS seems to be a bit of overkill to me.  But again - still reading up on it.

Comment: If you want to embed your styling directly into the markup, just use the `style` attribute. e.g. `<span style="font-size:24pt">This is a test</span>` The idea of CSS is to *separate* styling from content. Your proposal is to re-introduce embedded styling by the back door.

Comment: Yes - you can do it via styling but as you said - CSS is to separate styling.  However, the problem with CSS is that by divorcing it from what you are trying to do you make it so CSS can not be influenced by the HTML which reduces CSS to the level of an imbecile who is deaf, dumb, and blind to the needs of HTML yet affects HTML heavily.  If Javascript were handled the same way it would be totally useless.  I've decided I'm going to write my own PHP class for CSS.  Then it will meet my needs.  But SCSS is neat.

Comment: @IMSoP: I see what you mean about this being more of a forum thread.  How do you close it?  Do I need to use the "Answer Your Question" button?  Or can you close it somehow so it can't be updated anymore?  If you can do that - please do so.  Thanks in advance.  :-)

Comment: @MarkManning I've voted to close the question, but it is currently at 2 out of the required 5 votes. I *think* you can *delete* your own question (via a link just above these comments), but I don't know if there's limits to do with reputation and the question being answered already that will mean that option isn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in CSS.

But you can in SCSS. It is a rich(er) language that lets you do these things. But browsers don't support this directly. SCSS is 'compiled' into CSS, so you won't get the full flexibility that you describe.

See: http://sass-lang.com/guide

There are other varieties. SCSS is bases on SASS, but I think SCSS is preferred, because its syntax is closer to CSS and actually you can start with plain CSS files and add smarter additions to it as you go.

Another popular version is LESS. I've tried that in the past, but I thought it was less flexible and less intuitive than SCSS, therefore I switched. I have no hands-on experience with others.

Whichever you choose, you will always need to compile it into plain CSS for the browser to understand what is going on.

Comment: LESS has to installed into the server to work.  I do not have that capability. SCSS looks a bit better but I haven't finished reading up on it.

Comment: Could be on the server, but you could also run it from your development environment before deploying the CSS, so you only deploy the static CSS to your server. Another possibility would be to find a Javascript implementation, but I strongly advise not to do that.

Comment: Actually, I've decided to write a PHP class to handle this.  I did one for HTML using the __CALL() function.  Works great and I can do an entire TABLE statement by just calling $html->t(<id/name>, [<options>...]).  What it does is it has an equate table that is expanded and then referenced as needed.  In PHP, the __CALL() function says "Use this function if there isn't a defined function" so all HTML commands get caught by it as do the abbreviated commands.  It can auto-generate names via uniqid and the HTML command.  ($html->name = variable).  CSS should lend itself to this also.

Answer (score 0):

If you would add a javascript or jquery tag to your question, I'd probably come up with this approach:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('[data-class^="size"]').each(function(){
    var dynamicClass = $(this).data('class');
    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var matches = regExp.exec( dynamicClass );
    
    $(this).css('font-size', matches[1]);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-class="size(24pt)">This is a test</span>
```

Comment: Yes.  I could do something like that in jQuery but I was wondering why CSS doesn't just do something like this.  It isn't like you are trying to generate the CSS on-the-fly.  It is that the HTML could be scanned BEFORE actually generating the HTML web page to gather up the CSS commands and apply them.  I realize this would be an extra step the browsers would have to do (thus lots of committees arguing about this).  But HTML is dependent upon CSS so shouldn't HTML be able to have an input into what the CSS is?

Comment: We need to get back on it's basic understanding that CSS (or HTML for this matter) is used as presentational interface of a document, while what you're currently pondering into is somewhat functional, which is a different layer of it. This is like we're arguing that CSS is a programming language, while it in fact is not.

Comment: It has variables and I believe conditionals also.  So it is a quasi programming language already.  I see CSS more as a pre-document language.  Sort of like a pre-compiler.  Some languages now have complete languages for the pre-compiler stuff (ie: #if, #ifdef, etc...).  So I don't see this as being unreasonable or outside of what CSS can or should do.